# How do I aggregate and take the sum of a column based on an if condition in QlikSense?

Tags: qliksense

---

### name       rollno      marks

Raja        111R        10

Raja        111R        10

Rani        111R        10

### Ram         111Y        10

I'm trying an expression like this:
if(Name='Raja' OR Name='Ram', RollNo &' : '& round(aggr(sum(Marks),RollNo)/sum(total(Marks))*100,0.01)&'%')

My expected the answer is: Raja:30%, Ram:40%
Instead, the answer I'm getting currently is Raja:60%, Ram:40%

Answer (score 0):

You should have shown an example with inline load.

students:
Load * Inline [
Name, Roll_No, Marks
Raja, 10, 30
Raja, 10, 50
Ram, 12, 20
Ram, 12, 10];

Once you do that  create a table  with Dimension:
=Name 
and measure
=sum(Marks)/100 with Number formatting: Auto --> Number then 12.3%

If you want to show in a KPI  use :
if( Wildmatch(Name,'Raja'),sum( Marks)/100) for Raja 
if( Wildmatch(Name,'Ram'),sum( Marks)/100) for Ram

Never use IF( name='Raja'.....) always use Wildmatch( Fieldname,'Raja','Ram',etc,,etc)

aggr() is a very useful function  mainly used in set analysis but very heavy. Try to avoid  if possible .

More info go to :
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/June2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/wildmatch.htm